# Where is the login shell path set for /user/games etc..?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, path

When I launch a terminal in ubuntu I get following path on `echo $PATH`

```
/home/myuser/anaconda3/condabin:/home/myuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I want to remove those paths with games keyword from my `$PATH` , but I couldn't find from where the path like `/usr/games` , `/user/local/games` , `/usr/sbin` are set.

I tried to grep by `grep xxx ~/.* -l`

This gives files which set `/usr/bin` , `/usr/local/bin` etc..

But not for the above mentioned `games` and `sbin` paths.
How do I find from where it's set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not set in your personal environment, then it is set for every user. That means somewhere under `/etc`. Go to `/etc` and  issue:

```
grep usr.games * */* */*/* 2> /dev/null
```

On an Ubuntu installation, that will give you:

```
environment:PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
login.defs:ENV_PATH     PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
manpath.config:MANPATH_MAP      /usr/games              /usr/share/man
passwd:games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
passwd-:games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

The `passwd` files are for the user games, so of no importance. `manpath` is for reading the manuals. So, is you remove it from `environment` and `login.defs`, your gaming-days are over.

Comment: So to remove `games` entries from the PATH I should the remove the lines starting with `games` from the `passwd` file? I tried that, but it keeps coming back.

Comment: No. it is where the `PATH` is set that you need to look at.

Comment: I don't see it getting added to `PATH` in any of the files listed in cas's answer. Where else could it be getting added to `PATH`?

Answer (score 4):

There are several places it could be set.  To start with, it can be set in one or more of the following:

- any shell profile script (e.g. `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, etc)
- `/etc/login.defs`
- `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`
- `/etc/environment`
- `$HOME/.pam_environment`